# Is it possible to have a nested SELECT in a WHERE clause using dynamic queries?

Tags: database

I need to execute this SQL query using dynamic queries.

```sql
WHERE (node_field_data.status = 1) 
AND (node__field_document_places.entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM node__field_document_places where field_document_places_target_id = 51673))
```

This is the code I am using.

```php
$connection = Database::getConnection();
$query = $connection->select('node_field_data', 'node_field_data');

$query->condition('node_field_data.status',1);
$query->condition('node__field_document_places.entity_id',[ -- Can I do this here somehow? -- ], "IN");
```

I could technically run a separate query and put the IDs in an array. But I was hoping to avoid executing two different queries.

Is there a way to do this using dynamic queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible, see the [Subqueries can now be added to query conditions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2770421) change record for full details.

The canonical example is very similar to yours and should demonstrate how to refactor your code:

```
// Create a subquery, which is just a normal query object.
$subquery = db_select('test', 't2');
$subquery->addExpression('AVG(t2.age)');

// Create another query that adds a clause using the subquery.
$select = db_select('test', 't');
$select->addField('t', 'name');
$select->condition('t.age', $subquery, '<');
```

Don't forget to replace the deprecated `db_select()` with `$connection->select()`.